# How to configure w3 total cache on shared hosting (combination of Apache and nginx)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx, shared-hosting

### Server information

I am using shared hosting with Plesk panel. Where apache web server is running in the background with Nginx web server is in Front. Here is the more information

[http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/web-servers/apache-web-server-linux/apache-with-nginx.70837/](http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/web-servers/apache-web-server-linux/apache-with-nginx.70837)

I am using wordpress on shared hosting and want to enable [w3 total cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache). While enabling W3 Total cache, its generating .htaccess file. .htaccess file is unusable when Nginx running.

### Problem

Is there any way where we can add/modify Nginx configuration on shared hosting where apache is running on background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on modifying nginx configuration, I got another way to alter apache conf. Ref: http://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/customer-guide/websites-and-domains/hosting-settings/web-server-settings/apache-web-server-settings.72320/

Under pleask pannel >> Apache & nginx Settings >> Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links (unchecked this option)

After unchecking above option, my .htaccess code working fine. [image]